# How can I run a .html file directly from a Private repository in Github?

Tags: github

I'm embarrassingly new to git and GitHub and I've been trying to figure out how to run this index.html file from a private repository I've been given access to but isn't mine. I've looked at htmlpreview and rawgit, but those appear to only work for public repositories.

Any suggestions, instructions, and advice would be very gratefully received!

EDIT: I figured it out. First, clone the the repository locally. I did this by running "git clone https://github.com/{user}/{repository name}.git" in command line (might have to confirm username and password).  And then in a browser, go to file:///Users/ and click through to get to the index.html file and just click it. Not very technical sounding, but it works! Hope this helps other beginners!

Comment: Short answer, I don't think you can. You would need the ID/Pwd of the Repo to show the file, and the general public won't know what that is. What are you trying to accomplish, as you can freely host an HTML file hundreds of places.

Comment: I was told to just "try to run it and check it out". Sorry, not very helpful :/ but I'm working from very little here in terms of programming experience and know how :(

Comment: I want to do exactly this, but on an iPad, so cloning the repo and opening it with file:// is at least awkward if not impossible therefore the accepted answer doesn’t work for me :(.

Answer (score 4):

GitHub doesn't support HTML preview officially. You also shouldn't do that. Clone repository to Local PC, then view HTML file(s) on browser.

(Non-official, You can use: http://rawgit.com/ or http://htmlpreview.github.io/ )

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it does seems to be possible with `htmlpreview.github.io`. A solution found in the [following answer](https://github.com/htmlpreview/htmlpreview.github.com/issues/80#issuecomment-695334262):

> Your raw link should include a token by default after clicking "Raw" on GitHub.

So using the link with the token added and appended to `htmlpreview.github.io` did the trick for me. To summarize the steps:

- visit your page (index.html) on Github.
- click the raw button and copy the link currently in the search bar of your browser (you see it ends in `...token=XXXXXX`).
- prepend that link with `https://htmlpreview.github.io/?`, which will give you: `https://htmlpreview.github.io/?_the_link_you_just_copied_`